# How to customize error display logic in Formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

Formik has two options controlling when validation occurs: `validateOnChange` and `validateOnBlur`.

Problem with using `validateOnChange` - user will get errors as they start typing, say, email - because it is not valid when you just started to type first letters.

In case of `validateOnBlur` - let's say user typed in invalid email, left the field, returned and fixed to correct email - the error will be shown anyway until they leave the field, so this also does not work for me.

What I would like to achieve - first time validate a field on `blur` and starting that point - on `change`.

Every field should get this treatment individually.

I tried to find native ways to do it but couldn't find any, so I came up with this solution that I do not really like because it is not flawless:

`TL;DR:` I override standard `onBlur` and `onChange` coming from `Field`'s props and a) `onBlur` - mark field as changed once (probably I could use `touched` here) b) `onChange` I check if field was touched once and if so - call validation.

0) Disable validation

```
<Formik
  validateOnChange={false}
  validateOnBlur={false}
  ...
```

1) Added `changedFields` to my state

```
public state: IState = {
  changedFields: {}
};
```

2) Use special method that overrides default `onBlur` and `onChange`

```
<Field name="userName" render={(props: FieldProps<MyFormInterface>) => (
  <input type="text" label={'Name'} {...formikCustomValidation(props, this)} />
)}/>
```

3) The method. Passing Field's props and the parent component where state with `changedFields` is located.

```
function formikCustomValidation({ field, form }: FieldProps, ownerCmp: Component<any, any>) {
  return {
    ...field,
    onBlur: e => {
      if (field.value !== form.initialValues[field.name]) {
        ownerCmp.setState({
          changedFields: {
            ...ownerCmp.state.changedFields,
            [field.name]: true
          }
        });
      }

      field.onBlur(e);
      setTimeout(form.validateForm);
    },
    onChange: e => {
      field.onChange(e);
      if (ownerCmp.state.changedFields[field.name]) {
        setTimeout(form.validateForm);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

The question is - is there a way to do it easier?
The problem with this solution - if I Submit and untouched form and some errors come up - focus and fix value does not mark field as valid - because it is the first 'touch' and field is still in stat waiting for first blur state that supposed to make listen for 'changes'.

Anyway, maintaining this could be a pain, so looking for better solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this the default behaviour? Just don't set `validateOnChange` and `validateOnBlur` and Formik will do what you're describing.

Comment: Oh, I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you, mate.